# Interacting with flash content automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to automate the data scraping from [this site](https://www.peacebridge.com/index.php/historical-traffic-statistics/yearly-volumes), which uses flash to select date. I tried to use Puppeteer in NodeJS for this but with no luck, the browser does not interact with the flash buttons and returns the error message:

```
(node:4264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitForSelector' of undefined
at ~/scraper.js:27:19
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

(node:4264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4264) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Below is my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
puppeteer.use(require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-flash')());

(async () => {
  const args = [
    '--enable-webgl',
    '--enable-accelerated-2d-canvas'
  ];
  const options = {
    args,
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: false,
  };
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options)
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation()

  await page.goto('https://www.peacebridge.com/index.php/historical-traffic-statistics/daily-volumes')

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1853, height: 981 })

  let frames = await page.frames()
  const frame_627 = frames.find(f => f.url() === 'https://www.peacebridge.com/traffic.php')
  // await frame_627.select('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(1)', '2')

  await frame_627.waitForSelector('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(1)')
  await frame_627.click('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(1)')

  await frame_627.waitForSelector('body > .interface:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr > td')
  await frame_627.click('body > .interface:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr > td')

  await frame_627.select('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(1)', '3')

  await frame_627.waitForSelector('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(1)')
  await frame_627.click('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(1)')

  await frame_627.select('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(2)', '31')

  await frame_627.waitForSelector('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(2)')
  await frame_627.click('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(2)')

  await frame_627.select('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(3)', '2010')

  await frame_627.waitForSelector('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(3)')
  await frame_627.click('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .formfields:nth-child(3)')

  await frame_627.waitForSelector('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .buttons')
  await frame_627.click('.interface > tbody > tr > td > .buttons')

  await browser.close()
})()
```